# Why does I get the 'JSONDecoderError ' while streaming?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm getting the JSONDecoderError when streaming (crypto) price data with the module WebSockets, I'm making use of multiprocessing. I've seen in previous similar questions that the problem most of the time single quotes/double quotes were, but this isn't the case for me. Also, I don't get this error instant. Can someone help me?

My code:

*main.py*

```py
def main():
    pairs = ["BTC/USDT", "ETH/USDT", "LTC/"]

    for pair in pairs:
        pairPrice = getPrice(pair)
        if mainPrice != "0":
            pass

def getPrice(pair:str):
    path = CONSTS.allPairsPath + pair.replace("/", "") + ".json" 
    try:
        with open(path) as f:
            data = json.loads(f.read())
            return [float(data["b"]), float(data["a"])]
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return "0"

if __name__ == "__main__":

    p1 = Process(target=streaming.main)
    p2 = Process(target=main)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

*streaming.py*

```py
def main():
    # Import own modules
    import CONSTS
    # Import built-in modules
    import asyncio, json
    # Import extern modules
    import websockets

    async def stream():
        async with websockets.connect("wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/!bookTicker") as websocket:
            while True:
                data = await websocket.recv()
                data = json.loads(data)

                documentLoc = CONSTS.allPairsPath + data["s"] + ".json"
                with open(documentLoc, "w+") as f:
                    f.write(str(data).replace("'", '"')) # replace single quotes by double quotes

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    asyncio.ensure_future(stream())
    loop.run_forever()
```

*example JSON file*

```
{"u": 282430213, "s": "ADABTC", "b": "0.00000480", "B": "358426.00000000", "a": "0.00000481", "A": "26697.00000000"}
```

I get this 'JSONDecoderError' Error Message after a while (not instant):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 13, in main
    loop(mainPairs)
  File "main.py", line 71, in loop
    backwardsConvertPrice = getPrice(backwardsPair)[0] # Convert back to bitcoin
  File "main.py", line 87, in getPrice
    data = json.loads(f.read())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: The error message is telling you that the file is empty.  This might happen because `getPrice` opens the file in between it being opened for writing (which truncates the file) and the data being written.  If that's the case you can ignore the exception and try again later.

Comment: `str(data).replace("'", '"')` - don't do this, use `json.dump(s)`